# ERC721Order Orderbook in 0x API

Tags: 0x

I'm trying to post a signed ***ERC721Order*** to the ***0X Api orderbook*** deployed on Ropsten using the 0x protocol utils libraries (endpoint: *https://ropsten.api.0x.org/orderbook/v1/order*).

Unfortunately I receive this validation error message:

```
  "reason": "Validation Failed",
  "validationErrors": [
    {
      "field": "makerToken",
      "code": 1000,
      "reason": "should have required property 'makerToken'"
    },
    {
      "field": "takerToken",
      "code": 1000,
      "reason": "should have required property 'takerToken'"
    },
    {
      "field": "makerAmount",
      "code": 1000,
      "reason": "should have required property 'makerAmount'"
    },
    {
      "field": "takerAmount",
      "code": 1000,
      "reason": "should have required property 'takerAmount'"
    },
    {
      "field": "salt",
      "code": 1000,
      "reason": "should have required property 'salt'"
    }
  ]
}
```

The required fields seems related to the **LimitOrder** model.
Are the NFT Order supported in the 0x API orderbook?
Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFT orders are not currently supported on the 0x API orderbook.

If you'd like order persistance for 0x V4 NFT orders, you can use the Trader orderbook, which is specialized for NFT orders.

Docs here: https://docs.swapsdk.xyz/0x-v4/hosted-orderbook